# How to Fetch data from Firebase and Display it on Multitab in Android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to filter data in tab layout in Android app. If I click *Bollywood movie*, then only show *Bollywood category movie* and when I click *Hollywood* then only show *Hollywood category movie*.

I uploaded my [Firebase Database screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwUQqlVnhQ1bQWx2ems2RHFIekU/view?usp=sharing) and Android app source code on [GitHub](https://github.com/Kavan72/MovieQ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey @Kavan there is very simple solution for it just take to array one for hollywood(arr2) movie and one for bollywood(arr1) movie and in for loop just

```
if(movie.type.equals("bollywood")) {
    arr1.add(movie)
} else arr2.add(movie)
```

and pass the array to tab fragment and show it using adaprter

and for for firebase

```
@Override       
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
    Map<String, Object> payloadMap = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
    Map<String, Object> dataMap = (Map<String, Object>) payloadMap.get("data");
    app.getLogger().warn(dataMap.toString());
}
```

Comment: very very thank you for the answer. and i dont know how to add this on my source code. please i am the beginners in android so you solve my code in you suggest your answer but i am get it then you will solve my code in your way and after you solved my code you send my code on gitHub